# Can't detect when crosshair collides with target

Tags: python, pygame

New to pygame. Need advice with collision

I'm trying to make a simple pygame that a target moves across the screen and the user's control is a crosshair. You can move the crosshair around the screen freely with a mouse, and when you click it plays a gunshot noise, as if you were shooting the target. However, I am having trouble with detecting collision with the two.

```
if ammo > 0:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                gunshot.play()
                ammo -= 1
                print(ammo)
                if x == range(target_x,target_x+60) and y == range(target_y,target_y+60):
                    print('hit!')
                else:
                    print('miss!')
```

Here is a preview of my code that inside the function to make the gun, shoot. I have it if the x value of the mouse is equal to the range of the target x value, to the target x value + 60 since it is a 60x60 image. The same thing is happening with the y values of both. The range isn't working but I don't know how else to detect if the crosshair is in the value of the rect of the target

Answer (score 0):

If `[x,y]` corresponds to the coordinates of the mouse. Then `x` and `y` are simply integers not ranges, so you need to change `==` to `in`. You are checking whether `x` is **in** some range and `y` is **in** some range. This way is also more clear and readable since it the code

```
if x in range(x_target,x_target + 60)\
    and y in range(y_target, y_target + 60):
```

reads as

```
If mouse is in (on) target?
```

To enhance the readability even further you can do:

```
import itertools

x_target_range = range(x_target, x_target + 60)
y_target_range = range(y_target, y_target + 60)
if (x,y) in itertools.product(x_target_range, y_target_range):
    # do stuff
```

And probably even better to create separate function/method.

```
def target_hit(mouse, target):

    x_range = range(target.x, target.x + 60)
    y_range = range(target.y, target.y + 60)
    target_rect = itertools.product(x_range, y_range)

    return (mouse.x, mouse.y) in targe_frame


    # and somewhere down in the code
    if target_hit(mouse, target):
        # do stuff
```

The implementation of course depends on your data representation.